# How to get a particular part of associative array in php, laravel?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, arraylist, associative-array

I have array like

```
$data = [
    'phone' => '9999999999',
    'body' => 'Sample Message',
    'caption' => 'Sample',
    'filename' => 'Sample File.PDF'
];
```

I want to get a particular part from the array into another array like

```
$t_data = [
    'phone' => '9999999999',
    'body' => 'Sample Message'
];
```

how to do it?
And it should be a single line function

Comment: `$t_data=array(); $t_data['phone']=$data['phone']; $t_data['body']=$data['body'];`  this is too broad question

Comment: Hi there, please look at this [guide how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). what's missing is what you tried so far?

Comment: I would do something weird like: `$res = array_intersect_key($data, ['phone'=>0,'body'=>0])`  [Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/aa0b8987447133c0eb7e9f514a5f97e9f1530352). Just to confuse the junior developers, when they have to document it for me....  :-D

Comment: On its not because, i need a single line function like the answer i marked for this question

Comment: Please, who mark this question as not useful change it, take it as a request I think it is useful, and I also marked the correct answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the laravel helper array_only():

```
$t_data = array_only($data, ["phone", "body"]);
```

Comment: The docs are https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-array-only but this seems to be removed in laravel 5.7 and later, see https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers . Is there any alternative for newer Laravel versions?

Answer (score 0):

If you meant to take a slice of an array you can do like:

```
array_slice($data, 0, 2);
```

It will take first two values starting from zero position.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $t_data = [
    'phone' =>$data['phone'],
    'body'=>$data['body']

 ];
```

Answer (score -1):

Like this

```
print_r(array_intersect_key($data, ['phone'=>0,'body'=>0]));
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [phone] => 9999999999
    [body] => Sample Message
)
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/aa0b8987447133c0eb7e9f514a5f97e9f1530352)

Or as a function

```
function getArrayItems(array $array,$items,$separator=','){
     if(!is_array($items)) $items = array_filter(array_map('trim',explode($separator,$items)),function($i){
       return strlen($i);
     });
     return array_intersect_key($array, array_flip($items));
}

$data = [
    'phone' => '9999999999',
    'body' => 'Sample Message',
    'caption' => 'Sample',
    'filename' => 'Sample File.PDF'
];

print_r(getArrayItems($data, 'body')); // returns [body=>'Sample Message']
print_r(getArrayItems($data, ['body'])); // returns [body=>'Sample Message']
print_r(getArrayItems($data, ['body','caption'])); // returns [body=>'Sample Message','caption' => 'Sample']
print_r(getArrayItems($data, 'body,caption')); // returns [body=>'Sample Message','caption'=>'Sample']
print_r(getArrayItems($data, ' body , caption ')); // returns [body=>'Sample Message','caption'=>'Sample']
print_r(getArrayItems($data, 'body|caption','|')); // returns [body=>'Sample Message','caption'=>'Sample']
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e9144f39390c93c9a950b92bad286608083241dd)